# Find AD users with blank Password

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to find out users on my domain with blank password using powershell?

We already have a policy set for this but with too many admin teams managing different parts of domain just want to be sure if there is any active directory account with password = blank

Comment: [Query for blank passwords in Active Directory](http://seclists.org/pen-test/2007/Apr/21)

Comment: [Do You Allow Blank Passwords In Your Domain?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pfesweplat/2012/12/10/do-you-allow-blank-passwords-in-your-domain/) also has some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do for you:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=SomeOU,DC=mydomain,DC=forest,DC=local" | ForEach {
   $_.SamAccountName
   (new-object directoryservices.directoryentry "", ("domain\" + $_.SamAccountName), "").psbase.name -ne $null
   Write-Host ""
}
```

This will test all users for a blank password.

Alternatively - if you have a test password to use (you're looking for all "password123" users - try:

```
(new-object directoryservices.directoryentry "", ("domain\" + $_.SamAccountName), "password123").psbase.name -ne $null
```

I use this for validating users on a rolling basis to look for all AD user accounts which have been created but never logged onto (and therefore still use our default password).

I've just tested this on a PowerShell 4 windows 8.1 machine and it works - but this is also known to work from anything running PowerShell 4 and 5 (and possibly older)

Comment: That works! Thx :)